# Read csv into a list in clojure

Tags: clojure

I know there are a lot of related questions, I have read them but still have not gained some fundamental understanding of how to read-process-write. Take the following function for example which uses `clojure-csv` library to parse a line

```
(defn take-csv
  "Takes file name and reads data."
  [fname]
  (with-open [file (reader fname)]
    (doseq [line (line-seq file)]
      (let [record (parse-csv line)]))))
```

What I would like to obtain is data read into some collection as a result of `(def data (take-csv "file.csv"))` and later to process it. So basically my question is how do I return `record` or rather a list of records.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"doseq" is often used for operations with side effect. In your case to create collection of records you can use "map":

```
(defn take-csv
  "Takes file name and reads data."
  [fname]
  (with-open [file (reader fname)]
    (doall (map (comp first csv/parse-csv) (line-seq file)))))
```

Better parse the whole file at ones to reduce code:

```
(defn take-csv
  "Takes file name and reads data."
  [fname]
  (with-open [file (reader fname)]
    (csv/parse-csv (slurp file))))
```

You also can use clojure.data.csv instead of clojure-csv.core. Only should rename parse-csv to take-csv in previous function.

```
(defn put-csv [fname table]
  (with-open [file (writer fname)]
    (csv/write-csv file table)))
```

Comment: Nice. Now all is left is to `put-csv`, will you help?

Comment: Pay attention to doall : doall can
  be used to force any effects. Walks through the successive nexts of
  the seq, retains the head and returns it, thus causing the entire
  seq to reside in memory at one time.

Comment: Sure. But when you try realize next elements of lazy seq result you would get an exception because the file would be already closed at that moment. In order to fix that and reduce memory consumption you could pass a function which does the work with the result of a map to the `take-csv` as a parameter and use it within a `with-open` scope.

Answer (score 3):

With all the things you can do with .csv files, I suggest using clojure-csv or clojure.data.csv. I mostly use clojure-csv to read in a .csv file.

Here are some code snippets from a utility library I use with most of my Clojure programs.

```
from util.core

    (ns util.core
      ^{:author "Charles M. Norton",
        :doc "util is a Clojure utilities directory"}

      (:require [clojure.string :as cstr])
      (:import java.util.Date)
      (:import java.io.File)
      (:use clojure-csv.core))

(defn open-file
"Attempts to open a file and complains if the file is not present."

[file-name]
(let [file-data (try 
               (slurp file-name)
               (catch Exception e (println (.getMessage e))))]
  file-data))

(defn ret-csv-data
"Returns a lazy sequence generated by parse-csv.
 Uses open-file which will return a nil, if
 there is an exception in opening fnam.

 parse-csv called on non-nil file, and that
 data is returned."

[fnam]
(let [csv-file (open-file fnam)
      inter-csv-data (if-not (nil? csv-file)
                       (parse-csv csv-file)
                        nil)

      csv-data 
        (vec (filter #(and pos? (count %) 
           (not (nil? (rest %)))) inter-csv-data))]

    (if-not (empty? csv-data)
      (pop csv-data)
       nil)))

(defn fetch-csv-data
    "This function accepts a csv file name, and returns parsed csv data,
     or returns nil if file is not present."

    [csv-file]
        (let [csv-data (ret-csv-data csv-file)]
            csv-data))
```

Once you've read in a .csv file, then what you do with its contents is another matter. Usually, I am taking .csv "reports" from one financial system, like property assessments, and formatting the data to be uploaded into a database of another financial system, like billing.

I will often either `zipmap` each .csv row so I can extract data by column name (having read in the column names), or even make a sequence of `zipmap`'ped .csv rows.

Comment: Thank you. Still it would be interesting to hear your comment to reading the whole file into memory, which might be a problem for [very large files](http://clojurewise.blogspot.com/2011/02/reading-csv-files.html).

Comment: As far as I can tell it's a lazy sequence of maps. clojure-csv returns a lazy sequence, and zipmap does too. That's how I do it.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add this good answers, here is a full example

First, add [clojure-csv](https://clojars.org/clojure-csv) into your dependencies

```clj
(ns scripts.csvreader
  (:require [clojure-csv.core :as csv]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn take-csv
 "Takes file name and reads data."
 [fname]
 (with-open [file (io/reader fname)]
  (-> file
      (slurp)
      (csv/parse-csv))))
```

usage
`(take-csv "/path/youfile.csv")`